# Error When imorting PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I installed PyQt5 but when I try to use idle to run this code it doesn't work it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PRO/Desktop/a.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure was not found
```

Links : [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URiEk.png), [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pf6SD.png)

Comment: Where did you download PyQt5 and what version of python3 do you use?

Comment: I installed it using pip, pyhon 3.6.2

Comment: it seems that the version I install is not suitable with the version of python3.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running?

```
pip3 uninstall PyQt5
pip3 install PyQT5
```

Also, are the environment paths setup for PyQt5?